# Is the following power series expression valid?

Tags: proof-verification, power-series

So I know that for $z\in \mathbb{C}$ with $|z|<1$ we have that:
$$-\ln(1-z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^{n}}{n}.$$
If we let $z = xe^{it}$ where $t\in (0,\pi)$ with $|x|<1$ then $z^{n} = x^{n} \cos(nt) + ix^{n}\sin(nt).$ Furthermore if I express
$$1-z = 1-x e^{it} = re^{i\theta}$$
I get that 
$$-\ln(1-z) = -\ln(r) -i\theta$$
where $r = \sqrt{1-2x\cos(t) + x^2} $ and $\theta = \arctan(-x\sin(t)/ (1-x\cos(t))) $
then can I say that,
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\cos(nt)}{n}x^{n} = -\frac{1}{2} \ln(1-2x\cos(t) + x^2)$$
and 
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin(nt)}{n}x^{n} = \arctan\left(\frac{x\sin(t)}{1-x\cos(t)}\right)?$$

Comment: Should not it be $\tan\theta=\dfrac {-x\sin t}{1-x\cos t}$?

Comment: yeah I will correct that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you derivation is correct.

Comment: By the guidelines of this site, this post should be a comment and not a posted solution.